# I am trying to install pygame into PyCharm but for some reason, I keep getting ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pygame, pycharm

I have no idea why this is happening. Before I had the same error but it was saying I didn't have the wheel package installed. So I pip installed wheel and I still have this error but minus the part. I would show the error, but the entirety is too long. Here is the the part of the error that I think is causing the problem.

```
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pygame
  Building wheel for pygame (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pygame (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
    Running setup.py install for pygame: started
    Running setup.py install for pygame: finished with status 'error'

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

While I'm sure that it has something to do with pip, I have no idea how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:-
This is happening because your interpreter in Pycharm is not set to the right interpreter.

Step-1: you have to go to the edit configuration button situated at the topmost right screen of your pycharm window and after clicking on it select the interpreter you want from the list.

Step-2: Go to system settings (in Windows) or system preferences (in mac) and then select a project interpreter from the dropdown menu. From there, you can change the interpreter settings as well as install packages from the '+' sign. In this, you can also see the modules you have installed into the interpreter selected so choose the interpreter where you can see the pygame installed.
[image: Like this]

Comment: The problem is that I can't install the pygame module for some reason. In my question I pasted the part of error message that I think the solution but I don't understand what its telling me to do

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't understand why it worked, but I installed pygame with pip3 and then found the folder holding the pygame files and dragged it into the PyCharm folder storing the module files, and it worked! I checked pycharms and the module showed up in the interpreter setting. However, I still wish I knew why I was getting the error since I spent hours searching google for answers before coming up with this idea in a last ditch attempt. Also for some reason, on my Mac,
this install command didn't work:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

I had to instead use this:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame==2.0.0.dev6 --user
```